# Android Admob Banner and Menu Settings

Tags: menu, admob

So I am integrating AdMob banners in an android application. The Banner is situated at the bottom of view, working fine, not overlapping with the list view when scrolling and it's all good. I think that bottom position is a very good place to put the banner, but when clicking on the menu button, the menu does cover the banner. I guess this normal behavior but want to make sure it does not break the admob policies, specifically:

> Ads should not be placed very close to or underneath buttons or any other object which users may accidentally click while interacting with your application.

Does anybody have a similar situation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think until you dont have it very close to the menu it would be fine.

All you need to make sure is that it should not interfere with user inputs and produce incorrect clicks.

Its usually on a more case to case basis.

Comment: Dear @Vivek I have similare question, with navigation drawer, plz follow my question and put ur answer and I will marke it as true:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522808/does-navigation-drawer-over-admob-banner-violate-admob-policy