# Does Navigation drawer over admob banner violate Admob policy?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, admob

I am using Navigation-Drawer in my application. So I have created single activity with navigation_drawer layout. I am using fragments to change main content area data whenever user chooses a menu option from navigation drawer menu.

Now my problem is that I want to show admob ad on every screen and when opening the navigation drawer the ad will be under the navigation menu as shown in the bellowing picture:

[image]

Does it violate Admob policy? 
I have searched for this information but could not find a result. If you know kindly share with.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Note: I have messaged my question to the admob community and I have not received any anwser till now ....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns AdMob's policies, rather than programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following link you can see what ad placements will violate
admob policy: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

You'll be fine using ads in that way, one of my apps has a nav draw
and banner ads the same as your app. I think you'll be fine as long as
you're not placing the ad above any content the user wants to click -
seeing as the user can't actually click the ad when the nav draw is
open then you're not breaking any rules.

Comment: Thank you @tssomas :) It helped me a lot  :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: It is a violation of ads policy. I get a message for the same violation to fix it. You have some options. One, everytime drawer open, hide banner programatically.  Second, remove ad banner completely from that specific activity or fragment.